# One-One function check with piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I am little unclear on this problem. I need to prove that this is a one-one function. I know that I need to show $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$. But I don't know how this applies to piecewise functions.

$$f:x \rightarrow \begin {cases} |x| - 1 & x \leq -1 \\

-x^2 & x \geq 0 \end {cases}$$

Thanks for your help.

> > Edit:
> >     The answer by @Joe seems to make sense to me. But can you guys clarify this. Piecewise functions generally graph out as fragments. Does the one-one function property $f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$ differ in that case?

Comment: Hey, thanks for fixing that. I couldn't figure out how to get a piecewise function in latex. Good to know!

Comment: In answer to the edit, the one-to-one property doesn't differ in definition.  A better way to think might be if $x$ and $y$ are two different numbers, then $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are two different numbers.  In terms of graphs, you shouldn't be able to draw a horizontal line that intersects the graph in more than one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function is not one-to-one, since $f(0)=f(-1)=0$.

Comment: how is $f(0)=0$. By the way the domain is $(-\infty, -1]$ and $0 \notin (-\infty, -1]$

Comment: It's a piecewise function, my notation isn't very clear. But 0 can't be used for the first rule, and -1 can't be used for the second rule.

Comment: @Chandru:  The domain of the function is $(-\infty,-1]\cup[0,\infty)$.  It's piecewise, thus defined as different things on different parts of the domain.  To evaluate $f$ at $x=0$, use the rule $f(0)=-0^2=0$.  To evaluate $f$ at $x=-1$, use the rule $f(-1)=|-1|-1=0$.

Comment: @mathguy80: If those are two different functions and you need to show that each separately is one-to-one, then my answer does not apply.  But, you seem to be implying that they are two pieces of the same function.

Comment: @Chandru: How can the domain be $(-\infty,-1]$ and $f$ is defined as $-x^2$ for nonnegative $x$? The domain is $(-\infty,-1]\cup [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Joe It is piecewise, Here is a ![Better Notation](http://quicklatex.com/cache3/ql_92df33be18cbbe11237b1a20aa8fb1c5_l3.png)

Comment: 0 isn't used for the first rule and -1 isn't used for the second rule in Joe's argument.  Let x=-1.  Then via the first rule, f(-1)=1-1=0.  Let x=0.  Then via the second rule, f(0)=0.  So, f(-1)=f(0)=0, and thus f is not one-to-one.

Comment: @Asaf: Oh, the question has been edited. Please see the rollback.

Comment: I delete  my answer since the question has been edited

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a one-to-one function (also called injective sometimes) is that two different inputs are mapped to two different outputs.

That is, if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. Whether or not the function is defined by a formula, piecewise, not continuous, or polynomial... it does not matter.